# How to recognize Network Gateway VLAN for SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What I'm trying to get is how to understand that a VLAN is a network gateway one.

I'm trying to find all private Washington 4 datacenter and from the API I can get 4 vlans, but the portal allows to select one of 3 vlans. 
It seems this subnet/vlan cannot be used:

```
{"broadcastAddress"=>"10.170.23.127",
 "cidr"=>26,
 "gateway"=>"10.170.23.65",
 "id"=>1087855,
 "isCustomerOwned"=>false,
 "isCustomerRoutable"=>false,
 "modifyDate"=>"2016-02-03T14:51:45-05:00",
 "netmask"=>"255.255.255.192",
 "networkIdentifier"=>"10.170.23.64",
 "networkVlanId"=>1158237,
 "sortOrder"=>"4",
 "subnetType"=>"PRIMARY",
 "totalIpAddresses"=>"64",
 "usableIpAddressCount"=>"61",
 "version"=>4,
 "addressSpace"=>"PRIVATE",
 "datacenter"=>{"id"=>957095, "longName"=>"Washington 4", "name"=>"wdc04", "statusId"=>2},
 "networkVlan"=>
  {"accountId"=>872113,
   "id"=>1158237,
   "modifyDate"=>"2016-02-04T12:57:26-05:00",
   "name"=>"RZ",
   "primarySubnetId"=>1087855,
   "attachedNetworkGatewayFlag"=>false,
   "vlanNumber"=>844}}
```

If I pass this vlan id to request an order, I receive this error:

```
The backend VLAN #1158237 is a Network Gateway VLAN.
```

So this vlan cannot be used and the portal filters it out. That's ok, but the question is how to understand that this vlan should not be used?

Initially I thought attachedNetworkGatewayFlag will help, but it always false(see above). Any other property could be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation there is a property called "type":

> type
>
> The type of this VLAN.
>   Type: SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Type

For more information see: 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan

So you can get this information of the VLAN using object mask. For more information about object masks see: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-Masks

Using RestFul you could get all your VLANs and show the type using this request:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[type]
```

The request above will return a response like this:

```
 {
        "accountId": XXXXX,
        "id": XXXX,
        "modifyDate": "2015-01-28T07:39:10-06:00",
        "primarySubnetId": XXXX,
        "vlanNumber": XXX,
        "type": {
            "description": "Network VLAN belonging to a network gateway",
            "id": 2,
            "keyName": "GATEWAY",
            "name": "Gateway"
        }
    }
```

In case you are an user of the Ruby Client you can try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

SL_API_USERNAME = 'set me'
SL_API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: SL_API_USERNAME,
api_key: SL_API_KEY)

object_mask = 'mask[type]'

account_service = client['SoftLayer_Account']

vlans = account_service.object_mask(object_mask).getNetworkVlans()
print vlans
```

Also you may be interested in use objectFilters to get all the VLANS for a datacenter which are not Gateway type, you can achieve that using this RESTFUL:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateNetworkVlans?objectFilter={"privateNetworkVlans":{"primaryRouter":{"datacenter":{"longName":{"operation":"Washington 4"}}},"type":{"keyName":{"operation":"!=GATEWAY"}}}}

Replace: $username, $apiKey and Washington 4 (You can replace this for other datacenter) with your own information
```

For more information about objectFilters see:http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

And finally keep in mind that for orders only the VLANS of type "Standard" can be used. The valid types for VLANs are:

> ‘GATEWAY’, ‘STANDARD’, ‘INTERCONNECT’, ‘SWITCH_MANAGEMENT’,
>   ‘FIREWALL_HEARTBEAT’, ‘FIREWALL_CONTEXT’.

Regards

Comment: damn, 'type'  - that was simple, why didn't I see that? :) anyway, thanks for that